# "Sum of integral" or "result of integral"?

Tags: mathematics

Which is a more correct term for the result of mathematical integration, the *sum of an integral* or the *result of an integral*?

The first seems more on-point to me, but somehow the second sounds subjectively more correct and I am unsure which is better. Searching Google, Google Scholar and Math.SE for the two terms (in double quotes) yields a comparable number of results for both, so I don't think one is disallowed, but I can't tell if one of them is only used in specific mathematical contexts.

Comment: Google Books claims to have [About 4,790 results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+result+of+the+integral+is%22) for *the **result** of the integral is [whatever the result is],* but ***none at all*** for *the **sum** of the integral is...* Any level of prior research should have uncovered that, even if (like me) you have no real idea exactly what an "integral" means there (presumably because I was never taught "the calculus" at school).

Comment: Perhaps "sume of integral functions" if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't say the "sum of the integral". If you use a numerical integration method, you can certainly speak about summing the parts, but not the whole thing. That doesn't make sense. The idea of an integral expression already contains the idea of a sum. It doesn't matter whether you have or haven't evaluated the integrand, the expression still represents the "sum".

Comment: *The idea of an integral expression already contains ...  evaluated the integrand, the expression still represents the "sum".* -- This is already stated in a previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with, you have to distinguish between an *integral* as a function, where *value* would be the right word, and the process of integration itself, which is what both *result* and *sum* refer to.

*Result* refers to a process. Metaphorically, cranks have been turned, equations have been balanced, an infinite number of calculations have been made, and there is a result. Though in reality, what was really used was formulas like the fundamental theorem of calculus, or software like Mathematica. Either one will produce a result, and so will any other process.

But *result of an integral* can refer to either a definite integral (which is a number), or an indefinite integral (which is a formula). Not really a specific term, and again it doesn't refer to the functional aspects of derivation, which are at least as important as personal techniques for integration.

The problem with *sum*  is that it refers to addition; addition is part of the personal technique for calculating integral values. But as a process, integration is analogous to multiplication, not addition, just as derivation is analogous to division, not subtraction. Note that integrals are represented as **products** of a function with a differential, while derivatives as are represented as dividends of a function with a differential.

So *sum* can refer only to sum of the infinite series of (multiplied) areas that is the geometric basis of integral calculus, and that's not really good enough.

Comment: I wonder if you could expand on your opinion that "as a process, integration is analogous to multiplication, not addition." Certainly, the definition of any type of integral I know involves multiplication, but it also involves addition. After all, the symbol used for the integral is a reflection of its connection to summation. You seem, however, to believe that the connection to multiplication is more important, or stronger? This is interesting.

Comment: The point is that any physical process involving products -- like work or momentum -- is analyzed as an integral, and multiplication is the key metaphor to allowing students to see the relationship. The best way to think about laws like _F = ma_ is with integrals; if they see a product in the formula, they should be integrating. And that never involves infinite summation, except in theory -- in practice it involves typing or simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

*Sum* conflicts with "integral," which is a sum of a kind in itself. You say "the result of addition" or "the sum of the numbers," never "the sum of addition."

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I reject "sum" of an integral.  Use "sum" only for the result of addition.  The answer to an integration problem can be called the "result"; or it can be called the "value"; or more specifically it can be called the "integral".

Comment: So "result of integral" is actually redundant and should be "result of integration"?